# Autoware Compile Problem?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After doing the following steps

```
$ cd ~/Autoware/ros/
$ rosdep update
$ rosdep install -y --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro $ROS_DISTRO(getting error at this step)


sai@sai-Blade:~/Autoware/ros$ rosdep install -y --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro $ROS_DISTRO
executing command [sudo -H apt-get install -y gstreamer0.10-plugins-good]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package gstreamer0.10-plugins-good is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-good' has no installation candidate
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
  apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y gstreamer0.10-plugins-good] failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/326177/autoware-compile-problem??/) by [AM97](https://answers.ros.org/users/41623/am97/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2019-06-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [amc-nu](https://answers.ros.org/users/41091/amc-nu/) on 2019-06-18**:
you didn't mentioned, but due to the error, I think you are running on Ubuntu 18.04, using an old Autoware version.
Please pull latest `master` branch or `1.12 alpha` tag to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As @amc-nu mentioned, you are running an older (pre-1.120-alpha.1) version of Autoware that is not compatible with Ubuntu 18.04/ROS Melodic. See the updated instructions at https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/autoware/wikis/Source-Build to build version 1.12.0-alpha.2 or higher to work with Melodic.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2019-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0